# How to decode CBOR content type response

Tags: python, python-requests, request, cbor

I'm trying to automate some tasks using requests in Python. I was looking throught the network tab of the website and both request body and response body contain some weird characters.

[image: request payload]

The request content type is: application/cbor. How do I decode this data?

```
ÙÙ÷£gcontent¦cargFDIDLkcanister_idJðningress_expirywC{À¥/@kmethod_namemcanisterStatelrequest_typeequeryfsenderX®Þÿ]E)º×üó¹6B¦m¼õmsender_pubkeyXX0V0*HÎ=+B¡)43IO5¢ýÒHGÔ+iÃ+º<ÿfE48¾ØèÒÝ-t¦Y¿/íºÀµU'K>'Ð+eÄ\L{5j
```

Comment: maybe you need a library to decode CBOR format https://pypi.org/project/cbor2/